# EC2 instanse with Jenkins installed becomes not available when Jenkins build is started

Tags: docker, jenkins, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, continuous-integration

I've installed Jenkins on the AWS EC2 instance with RedHat.
Security groups are configured to allow all HTTP and SSH traffic.

Jenkins is installed via docker-compose.

When I start a test job Jenkins can clone the code from a GitHub repository and execute shell commands from Jenkinsfile that are present in the repository.

When I try to start a job with maven build - the EC2 instance becomes not available: I cannot connect it via SSH not from my terminal nor via AWS connect.
On the AWS console instance health is shown as "healthy".
EC2 instance reboot doesn't help.

Any ideas about what I may do wrong?

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports: 
      - "80:8080"
    volumes: 
      - "$PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
    networks:
      - net 
networks:
  net:
```

jenkins_home is created, tried to change $PWD to a full path.

Jenkins could download code from Github, so the problem is not in security groups as I understand.

Will try to install Jenkins without docker-compose, but anyway want to figure out the reasons for this problem.

Thank you.

======

Some extra info to Przemysław Puchajda answer

The reason of the problem was the EC2 instance resource exhaust, as  Przemysław Puchajda mentioned.

In my case, I solved the problem by configuring a swapfile.
Swap is a space on a disk that is used when the amount of physical RAM memory is full.

1. In Jenkins check `Manage Jenkins` > `Manage Nodes and Clouds`
   If you see that for Built-In Node Free Swap Space is 0, it
   means that Jenkins doesn't have an access to a swapfile.
   It can be if the swapfile or swap partition was not configured or
   if Jenkins is running in docker in not-privileged mode.

[image: Free swap space - 0 B]

2. Check if the swap is configured on your host:
   `free | grep -i Swap`
   The swap is not configured if the result is
   `Swap:            0          0          0`
   Also you can use `swapon` command.
3. Configure a swapfile

```
sudo fallocate -l 2G /swapfile #set your size instead of 2G
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
sudo vi /etc/fstab
paste a line : /swapfile swap swap defaults 0 0
#check swap is configured 
sudo free -h
```

3. Make sure docker-compose.yml has `privileged: true` line under services:jenkins. I'm adding a full docker-compose.yml I used down below.
4. Restart container:

```
sudo docker compose down 
#sudo docker-compose down for old version of docker 
sudo docker compose up -d
```

My docker-compose.yml with privileged mode:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
  jenkins:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts
    privileged: true
    user: root
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
      - 50000:50000
    container_name: jenkins
    volumes:
      - /home/ec2-user/jenkins_compose/jenkins_configuration:/var/jenkins_home
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  agent:
    image: jenkins/ssh-agent:jdk11
    privileged: true
    user: root
    container_name: agent
    expose:
      - 22
    environment:
      - JENKINS_AGENT_SSH_PUBKEY=your_private_key_for_ssh_connection
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If checking the Jenkins logs is not an option (instance hangs) - try to log in to the instance and tail -f /var/log/messages and docker logs -f  before running the build and trace the moment it stops responding. Correlate the time with the cloudwatch logs - without cloud watch agent you won't be able to check the memory metric which could be the route cause of an issue here - so consider installing cloudwatch agent first.

The only reason for this behaviour is the EC2 instance resource exhaust - the instance become unoperational and in most cases this will not affect instance health status under the console or it will after some period of time. This is because the check works by periodically sending TCP requests to the instance's IP address and port number. If the instance responds to the request with a success status code it will not affect the status health in console. In most cases the instance will still respond to TCP but you will be unable to log to the instance.

Confirm the instance resources are not saturated - during the job - if yes - adjust the instance size or consider to offload the jenkins to another ec2 optionally switch do aws codebuild.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Is it possible that the reason for the issue is EC2 instance resource exhaust and instance reboot doesn't make Jenkins available? Thank you

Comment: You were right about EC2 instance resource exhaust. I managed to solve the problem by setting up a swapfile. But still don't understand why after instance reboot  I couldn't connect to the EC-2 instance and Jenkins was not available.

Comment: After the instance exhaust and restart from EC2 console the process will take some time (even several minutes) - ec2 will need to process reboot signal and during this time the instance status can flicker - this could be misleading. Other option is that depending on the Jenkins configuration/distribution/image you have Jenkins can re-run the jobs after restart automatically - I believe Jenkins configuration is not the case here.